# How does error page call asyncContext.complete()?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, asynchronous

The [javadoc of the javax.servlet.AsyncContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/AsyncContext.html) interface says (many times):

> If no matching error page was found, or **the error page did not call
>   complete()** or any of the dispatch() methods, call complete().

How can the error page (say, error.jsp) call asyncContext.complete() ?
Does that even make sense ?
Or does "error page" mean something else ?

I looked at the JSP spec and there is not even a mention of asyncContext !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an error JSP, you could call:

```
request.startAsync();
```

If an async request was already started, it will return the same `AsyncContext` that was created when the async request was initially started.  From here, one could call `complete()` on it.

But you certainly don't have to do this.  If you read the spec it states that the container must call `complete()` if nothing else calls it.

Comment: [a sand becomes a pearl](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/) ! thanks !